# Netlogo: don't know why this abs operation always give the same result

Tags: netlogo

I have a set of 100 bits named bits, i just want to do this operation:
100 - absolute_value( # of 1's - # of 0's ).  I've tried various forms, one of these like:

```
100 - abs (length filter [x -> x = 1] bits - length filter [x -> x = 0] bits)
```

But no matter what, the result always is 100, i don't understand why because if i remove the "100 - " the result of the abs operation alone is diferent than 0.
Any advice will be apreciated, also i've notice that when i do a random request consecutively the result doesn't change too much

```
turtles-own [
  bits
  fitness
]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles population-size [
  set bits n-values world-width [one-of [0 1]]
  ifelse fitness-function?
  [ calculate-fitness-alt ]
  [ calculate-fitness ]
   hide-turtle
]    

to calculate-fitness-alt
 set fitness 100 - abs (length filter [x -> x = 1 ] bits - length filter [x -> x =   0 ] bits)
end
```

Comment: That code looks right and seems to behave correctly when I test it. Where is `bits` coming from?

Comment: set bits n-values world-width [one-of [0 1]]

Comment: That also looks okay. Can you edit your question to include the code where the above (`100 - ...`) is called? My only theory right now is that some parentheses are needed somewhere to get it to associate correctly.

Comment: i included the code, fitness function is from a switch

Comment: Thanks! Ya, that code should definitely be working. When I run it, I get expected variance. Are you sure `fitness-function?` is on?